# Polymorphism between std::unordered_set and std::vector?

Tags: c++, stl

I have a function in my code which takes in a C++ container object, and reads each element in it using a loop. The function looks a bit like this:

```
void function(std::unordered_set<unsigned int> container)
{
    for(auto it = container.begin(); it != container.end(); it++)
    {
       /* Do something */
    }
}
```

However, I would like this function to also accept containers of type std::vector. As you can see from the code, the body of the function need not be aware of the type of the container (it can just access each element using *it). How can I achieve this without having redundancy in my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like:

```
template<typename ContainerType>
void function(ContainterType container)
{
  ... 
}
```

should do what you want.

You need a template, becuase there isn't a common base-class for STL containers, so they aren't passable as "this is the baseclass, take any derived type".

Assuming you don't want to modify the container, I'd go with:

```
template<typename ContainerType>
void function(const ContainterType& container)
{
   ...
}
```

to avoid having a copy made.

Answer (score 2):

For performance reasons and for a more "generic programming" (as opposed to OOP) view of the world or whatever STL containers aren't designed with polymorphism in mind; instead, as STL algorithms do, you are expected to expose a generic iterator-based interface and work with whatever iterator type that is given to you.

Comment: +1.  More explicitly, `template <typename Iterator> void function(Iterator begin, Iterator end)`, called ala `function(container.begin(), container.end())`, has the benefit of also accepting e.g. pointers to array elements, input iterators etc..